# Displaying fields with many to many relationship laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm the beginner of laravel 5.4. I just want to ask. I want to display in Assignments table the Collectors but it doesn't show.

[Screenshot of the Assignments Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyMLW.jpg)

Code in my Assignment index.blade.php

```
<td>{{ $assignment->collector['firstname'] }} {{ $assignment->collector['lastname'] }}</td>
```

Assignment.php model

```
public function collectors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Collector::class);
}
```

Collector.php model

```
public function assignments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Assignment::class);
}
```

AssignmentsController

```
public function index()
{
    $assignments = Assignment::all();

    return view('assignments.index', compact('assignments'));
}
```

I search to how to display the collectors with both many to many relationship. I read the doc about using pivot but I had still errors about that. Can you help me resolving this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$collector` is an object, not an array. Use `->` syntax to access properties on individual collector models:

```
$collector->firstname
```

Since the relationship is many to many you need two loops:

```
@foreach($assignments as $assignment)
     @foreach($assignment->collectors as $collector)
        <td>{{ $collector->firstname }} {{ $collector->lastname }}</td>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

If you find you often need two fields together, like first and last names, you can create an accessor on the `Collector` model to easily join them:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->getAttribute('firstname') . ' ' . $this->getAttribute('lastname');
}
```

Allowing you to then do:

```
@foreach($assignments as $assignment)
     @foreach($assignment->collectors as $collector)
        <td>{{ $collector->fullname }}</td>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I got the error of "Trying to get property of non-object " at line 32 
<td>{{ $assignment->collector->firstname }} {{ $assignment->collector->lastname }}</td>

Comment: That's likely because there is no collector associated with the assignment. Updated the answer with one way of accounting for this case.

Comment: I try your updated version but the problem it doesn't display the collectors even though the collector has its value

Comment: Totally overlooked the type of relationship on the models. The problem is that it's a many to many relationship. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes it's many to many. I try the new one but it produce an error SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ecoteneo.assignment_collector' doesn't exist. I add the code of index function in assignments controller. Is there need to add something in that one?

Comment: The error is correct for the relationship type, when using a man-to-many you need an intermediate table linking the two tables together. [Many-to-Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Okay I got it.. Thank you!